# Java Dynamic Web Project HTTP Status 500 - Error instantiating servlet class

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets

I use Apache Tomcat Server 8.0, getting HTTP Status 500 - Error instantiating servlet class.

[image]

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>THTTagTravel</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

In index.jsp:

```
<FORM action="TestServlet" method=get> 

...

<Input Type=submit value="submit">  
</FORM>
```

## Update：

The database I used was constructed by Neo4J 2.2, I was using Neo4j2.3 in this project. I reconstructed the database, on other modification needed.

Comment: Look in server log for full stack trace with root cause(s). The answer is just right there in bottommost root cause.

Answer (score 1):

1. add your servlet class in web.xml

   ```
   <servlet>
       <servlet-name>TestServlet</servlet-name>
       <servlet-class>com.example.servlet.TestServlet</servlet-class>
   </servlet>
   <servlet-mapping>
       <servlet-name>TestServlet</servlet-name>
       <url-pattern>/servlet/TestServlet</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>
   ```
2. Make sure your path of servlet i.e. /yourPorjectDirectory/WEB-INF/classes

Comment: Could you explain a little more about 2? what else shall I do?  I already add the code after </welcome-file-list>

Comment: Where is your present location of the com.example.servlet.TestServlet?

Comment: /PorjectDirectory/Java Resources/src/com/example/servlet/TestServlet.java

Comment: move your com.example.servlet/TestServlet.java to /projectDirectory/WEB-INF/classes. Compile it and then run

Comment: I create a folder class then move TestServlet.java in that folder, now I got 404 error

Comment: I repeat please place your TestServlet.class file in /webapps/yourProjectDirectory/WEB-INF/classes folder

Comment: folder name is classes not class

Comment: This answer is nonsense. If the servlet were not properly registered in web.xml and were absent in WEB-INF/classes, then the container would never be able to find it nor have attempted to instantiate it in first place. The error message would never have contained the servlet class name. Whoever two headlessly upvoted this answer, please be careful to not destroy the credibility of Stack Overflow.